# Connection column in stage history related list

Tags: opportunity-history

what is this column for?
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: Do you have Salesforce to Salesforce enabled in this org?

Comment: i dont think so. I just want to know what does that connection column mean what would that contain.